# Check whether the binding property exists or not

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatrigger

I've a situation in which there is a common control which is used couple of places in application.

Now in this i've a data trigger on a property say A. i.e.

DataTrigger Binding={Binding A} .......

Now it may be possible that property A doesn't exist in view model, in that case i need to add another trigger based on property B (which exist in that ViewModel).

Something like:

Multidatatrigger

```
DataTrigger Binding A - doesn't exist
DataTrigger Binding B
```

Do something.....

Can someone suggest me how i should approach for this. . As if i try to do as such then binding exception will be thrown because A doesn't exist in current View Model. Or any other approach would work here...
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can make use of [PriorityBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

```
<DataTrigger Value="XXX">
  <DataTrigger.Binding>
     <PriorityBinding>
        <Binding Path="A"/>
        <Binding Path="B"/>
     </PriorityBinding>
  </DataTrigger.Binding>
  <Setter ...
</DataTrigger>
```